# How can I know redux-form resetForm() is completed?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I use `redux-form` + `react` in my project:

```
//My components
<button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.getBuildingList.bind(this)}>Search</button>
<button type="button"  onClick={this.resetBuildForm.bind(this)}>Reset</button>

//resetBuildingForm function
resetBuildingForm(){
    let { dispatch, resetForm, list } = this.props;
    resetForm();
    //when I resetForm, I want to search again
    this.getBuildingList();
}
```

when I resetForm, I want to search again, but when I get state in redux-form, I get the state is old but not new, How can I know when the resetForm event is complete and the state is updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could listen for when your form goes from `dirty` to `pristine`.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if(this.props.pristine && !prevProps.pristine) {
    // we just reset
    this.getBuildingList()
  }
}
```

Then you can just call `this.props.resetForm()` to initiate the reset.

Answer (score 3):

This might be helpful for someone new like me.
Since reduxForm version 6, the `this.props.resetForm()` already changed to `this.props.reset()`.

See the issue [here](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1208).